# SQL Server 2008 log will not truncate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I consider myself a very experienced SQL person. But I'm failing to do these two things:

- Reduce the size of the allocated log.
- Truncate the log.

  DBCC sqlperf(logspace)

returns:

```
Database Name   Log Size (MB)   Log Space Used (%)  Status
ByBox       1964.25     30.0657         0
```

The following does not work with SQL 2008

```
DUMP TRANSACTION ByBox WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
```

Running the following does nothing either

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE ('ByBox_1_Log' , 1)
DBCC shrinkdatabase(N'bybox')
```

I've tried backups. I've also tried setting the properties of the database - 'Recover Model' to both 'FULL' and 'SIMPLE' and a combination of all of the above. I also tried setting the compatibility to SQL Server 2005 (I use this setting as I want to match our production server) and SQL Server 2008.

No matter what I try, the log remains at 1964.25 MB, with 30% used, which is still growing.

I'd like the log to go back down near 0% and reduce the log file size to, say, 100 MB which is plenty. My database must hate me; it just ignores everything I ask it to do regarding the log.

One further note. The production database has quite a few replicated tables, which I turn off when I perform a restore on my development box by using the following:

```
-- Clear out pending replication stuff
exec sp_removedbreplication
go
EXEC sp_repldone @xactid = NULL, @xact_segno = NULL,
     @numtrans = 0, @time = 0, @reset = 1
go
```

Trying:

```
SELECT log_reuse_wait, log_reuse_wait_desc
FROM sys.databases
WHERE NAME='bybox'
```

Returns

```
log_reuse_wait  log_reuse_wait_desc
0   NOTHING
```

How can I fix this problem?

---

Looking at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/9f9ae5c5-3031-4963-bb16-c7ed05d9890a/) and setting the recovery model to FULL I have tried the following:

```
USE master
GO

EXEC sp_addumpdevice 'disk', 'ByBoxData', N'C:\<path here>\bybox.bak'

-- Create a logical backup device, ByBoxLog.
EXEC sp_addumpdevice 'disk', 'ByBoxLog', N'C:\<path here>\bybox_log.bak'

-- Back up the full bybox database.
BACKUP DATABASE bybox TO ByBoxData

-- Back up the bybox log.
BACKUP LOG bybox TO ByBoxLog
```

which returned:

```
Processed 151800 pages for database 'bybox', file 'ByBox_Data' on file 3.
Processed 12256 pages for database 'bybox', file 'ByBox_Secondary' on file 3.
Processed 1 pages for database 'bybox', file 'ByBox_1_Log' on file 3.
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 164057 pages in 35.456 seconds (36.148 MB/sec).

Processed 2 pages for database 'bybox', file 'ByBox_1_Log' on file 4.
BACKUP LOG successfully processed 2 pages in 0.056 seconds (0.252 MB/sec).
```

Perfect! But it's not.

And DBCC SHRINKFILE ('ByBox_1_Log' , 1) now returns with

```
DbId    FileId  CurrentSize MinimumSize UsedPages   EstimatedPages
7   2   251425  251425  251424  251424
```

and DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE) still reports 30% usage.

I think I may have to resign myself to the fact there could well be a bug in SQL Server 2008, or that my log file has been corrupted in some manner. However, my database is in good working order, which leads me to think there is a bug *(shudders at the thought)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Found the solution!**

I added a load of data to the database, so the log was forced to expand. I then removed the uneeded data to get my database back to how it was.

Backup and voila, a perfect 0% log.

So the solution is to make the log expand.

Comment: Run: DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE)
This will tell you how much space is free. Create a scratch table and keep adding rows of data until your log is forced to expand. You will know this when DBCC SQLPERF(Logspace) hits100, then drops after its expanded. drop your scratch table. backup. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 36):

In my situation, I had a 650 MB database with a 370 GB log file in SQL Server 2008. No matter what I tried, I could not get it to shrink down. I tried everything listed as answers here but still, nothing worked.

Finally, I found a very short comment somewhere else that did work. It is to run this:

```
BACKUP LOG DatabaseName TO DISK = N'D:\Backup\DatabaseName_log.bak'
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE('MyDatabase_Log', 1)
GO
```

This caused the log file to shrink from 37 GB down to 1 MB. Whew!

Comment: **THANK YOU** for being straight to the point. Drives me nuts when I get a dissertation on why a practice is bad, rather than answering the question. **NOTE:** I tried this and ran into the message _'cannot shrink log file because the logical log file located at the end of the file is in use.'_ I had to set Recovery Mode to SIMPLE before it released the space. I changed it back to FULL after freeing the disk space.

Answer (score 12):

I found *[DBCC SHRINKFILE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx)* (MSDN).

The following example shrinks the log file in the AdventureWorks database to 1 MB. To allow the `DBCC SHRINKFILE` command to shrink the file, the file is first truncated by setting the database recovery model to SIMPLE.

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
-- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.
DBCC SHRINKFILE (AdventureWorks_Log, 1);
GO
-- Reset the database recovery model.
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```

Comment: **THIS** is the much simpler answer. As long as you aren't in production, this works like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

### **Beware of the implications of changing recovery models!!**

And now for one more sobering thought for all you **production [DBAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_administrator)** thinking about using the script:

BEFORE YOU CHANGE THE RECOVERY MODEL FROM FULL TO SIMPLE... there's no worries if you're in a development/[QA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality_assurance) environment. But if you're in a production environment where you're responsible to ensure full recovery of data in the event of an issue, you may want to take a closer look at what BOL says regarding doing this (see BOL under: "Managing Databases" -> "Transaction Log Management" -> "Recovery Models and Transaction Log Management"):

A database can be switched to another recovery model at any time. However, switching from the simple recovery model, is unusual. Be aware that if you switch to the full recovery model during a bulk operation, the logging of the bulk operation changes from minimal logging to full logging, and vice versa.

After switching from the simple recovery model

> If you switch from the full or bulk-logged recovery model to the simple recovery model, you break the backup log chain. Therefore, we strongly recommend that you back up the log immediately before switching, which allows you to recover the database up to that point. After switching, you need to take periodic data backups to protect your data and to truncate the inactive portion of the transaction log.
>
> After switching to the simple recovery model
>
> If you switch from the full or bulk-logged recovery model to the simple recovery model, you break the backup log chain. Therefore, ***we strongly recommend that you back up the log immediately before switching, which allows you to recover the database up to that point.*** After switching, you need to take periodic data backups to protect your data and to truncate the inactive portion of the transaction log.

Really? "***We strongly recommend that you back up the log immediately before switching, which allows you to recover the database up to that point.***" I cannot understand why this *little* tidbit of information is hidden in a section named "After switching to the simple recovery model" making most "normal people" think they can go ahead and switch it and then continue or come back and read this after changing it.

### Rant

To Microsoft: So, please correct me if I'm wrong, if I fail to do the t-log backup BEFORE changing from FULL to SIMPLE and lo and behold my database gets corrupted somehow (ever heard of [Murphy's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law)?) right before I'm able to take a backup... then I'm screwed, right?  If switching the recovery model of my ****production**** database from FULL to SIMPLE is something that can break the backup log chain such that if I fail to take a transaction log backup before doing it (like it suggests above) ***I'm potentially going to lose data***, then WHY THE HECK AREN'T YOU HIGHLIGHTING THAT IN A BLINKING MARQUEE MAKING IT A BIGGER DEAL than you seem to be??!  You should literally be grabbing me by the shirt and slaping me to get my attention (so to speak) and warning me of the importance of this UPFRONT!!

Answer (score 8):

Another easy way to reduce the size of the log file, is to:

- Backup logs
- Full backup of the database
- Shrink the logs file
- Backup logs again
- Shrink the logs file again

In this way you don't have to modify any database parameters and your logs file is 1 MB sized.

Answer (score 5):

I've always hated the way SQL Server handles the physical shrinking of log files. Please note that I've always done this via Enterprise Manager/SQL Server Management Studio, but it seems that when you shrink/truncate the log file, the physical size of the log file will not reduce until after doing a full backup on the database's data file, and then backing up the log file again. I could never nail down the exact pattern, but you could try and see what the exact sequence is. However, it has always involved doing a full backup of the data file.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with SQL Server's handling of log files. I fail to see how it could be done any other way. Most times there are problems, the database has not had a proper maintenance plan created and scheduled.

Comment: Bollocks. You vote me down without proving I'm wrong? And I'm not stating there is anything wrong with the way SQL Server handles log files, I'm saying I don't like it. You MUST do a full backup before the physical file shrinks.

Comment: Hello from 2017. Hit the same problem, fixed with full backup, log backup, diff backup, log backup - then I was able to shrink file. Full+log is really not enough. So, definitely a bug somewhere :)

Answer (score 4):

Try running

```
DBCC OPENTRAN
```

to check if there are any open transactions.

Comment: Thanks, but I get "No active open transactions.". It definately looks like it has open transactions but doesn't I'm beginning to suspect either a corrupted log file, or a bug in sql server 2008.

Answer (score 4):

This will sound kind of stupid, but I find that I have to perform two full database and log file backups to be able to shrink the database.

When using [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio), after doing a full database backup followed by a full transaction log backup, the shrink files page shows plenty of free space available, but it will not truncate the log files.

However, when I run a second full backup of both the database and the log file, I find that the full backup of the transaction log is much much smaller as it appears to only be backing up the new changes since the last backup.

Once this second backup is complete, I run the shrink tool again within the management studio. It still shows that there is plenty of available free space, but this time when I click OK, the log file reduces in size.

So, try the following.

1. Take a full backup of both the database and the log file. If you check within the shrink tool, you should see that there is now plenty of available free space in the log file. However clicking OK won't remove the free space.
2. Take a second full backup of both the database and the log file. You should find the full backup of the database is similar in size to the first full backup. The size of the full transaction log backup should be much smaller.
3. Run the shrink tool on the log file and with any luck, the log file should reduce in size. The last time I did this, it reduced from 180 GB to 12 MB and the shrink tool states that there is still 10 MB of available free space within the file.

Comment: this worked perfectly for me. I required a Full recovery model due to mirroring and changing the recovery model to 'simple' was not an option.

Comment: Worked for me too. Found out that it broke my automated SQLBackupAndFTP though. Needed to set it up again.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found a solution for the logfile shrink problem. All of the previous options did not work for me and did not shrink the logfile to the required size. The solution I found is:

- Backup your database
- Set the recovery mode to simple
- Detach the database with [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio)
- Delete the logfile
- Attach the database without the logfile. In the lower half of the "add screen" you get a line which says that the logfile is missing
- Click remove for this line and OK for the attach
- Set the recovery mode back to full

Answer (score 2):

I know what you mean - SQL server can be a bit maddening that way.  Here is some sample code to try out.  In essence, it truncates the log file and *then* tries to shrink the file.  Let me know how it works.  One other thing...you wouldn't have uncommitted transactions, would you?

```
Use YourDatabase
GO

DBCC sqlperf(logspace)  -- Get a "before" snapshot
GO  

BACKUP LOG BSDIV12Update WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY;  -- Truncate the log file, don't keep a backup
GO

DBCC SHRINKFILE(YourDataBaseFileName_log, 2);  -- Now re-shrink (use the LOG file name as found in Properties / Files.  Note that I didn't quote mine).
GO

DBCC sqlperf(logspace)  -- Get an "after" snapshot
GO
```

**Update:** Simon notes that he is getting an error on the BACKUP command. I didn't realize that "Truncate_only" has been discontinued in SQL Server 2008 when I answered earlier.  After a bit of research, the recommended steps to shrink the log file is to (a) Change the Recovery Model to Simple and then (b) shrink the file using DBCC ShrinkFile as above.  Unfortunately, you mention that you already tried setting the recovery model to Simple so I assume that you also ran the DBCC Shrinkfile afterward.  Is this correct?  Please let me know.

Comment: BACKUP LOG bybox WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
gives me:
Msg 155, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
'TRUNCATE_ONLY' is not a recognized BACKUP option.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that is correct. I've tried shrinking in both FULL and SIMPLE modes. Its really odd.

Answer (score 2):

This can be a pain, and there are many things it could be.  The first thing you should make sure of is that there is not a "stuck" transaction.  If you have a transaction that never closes, you cannot ever shrink the log.  Run "DBCC OPENTRAN" to find the longest running transaction.

Also, make sure you reorganize (I think that's the proper term) and move everything to the beginning of the file before shrinking.

Comment: Thanks, but I get "No active open transactions."
Plus I've tried reorganizing everything to the beginning too. I may even try and drop the database and restore, but would love to know how to sort this little critter properly.

Comment: Any incompletely rolled-back, transactions?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but look here:
http://blog.crankybit.com/shrink-the-unshrinkable-sql-transaction-log/

Answer (score 2):

Reading the answers I hardly believe that they are written by DBAs. Basic golden rules:

1. In any database before you performing any maintenance, including
   shrinking the log, you should perform a full backup.
2. Carry out any database maintenance, including shrinking, when
   nothing else is happening on that particular database for the whole
   duration of the maintenance. If it is necessary, suspend
   non-essencial applications. Always keep it in mind that the healthy
   database is the soul of any applications interacting with it.

After all this, the following commands for shrinking the database's transaction log always worked fine with me on SQL Server 2005 and later SQL Server versions:

```
USE DatabaseName
GO
-- Truncate the Transaction log
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
CHECKPOINT
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET RECOVERY FULL
GO
-- Shrink the Transaction Log as recommended my Microsoft.

DBCC SHRINKFILE ('database_txlogfilelogicalname', [n -size to shrink in MBytes])
GO
 -- Pass the freed pages back to OS control.
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (DatabaseName, TRUNCATEONLY)
GO
-- Tidy up the pages after shrink
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE (0);
GO
-- IF Required but not essential
-- Force to update all tables statistics
exec sp_updatestats
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I have finally come to the conclusion that there is a bug in SQLServer 2008.

I've tried everything, and every combination I can think of. I've backed up the database, dropped it, re-created it, restored it. Exact same problem.

I also ran:

```
DBCC CHECKDB
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE (bybox)
```

And all checks out ok.

Roll on the next service pack is all I can say.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2012): I had an issue where no log file (and all were already in SIMPLE recovery) would shrink.

This worked for me... I restarted the SQL Server instance (because I could) and every one of those bad boys shrunk.

Whatever was holding it up from shrinking was released with the restart.  This is only good for emergencies (or when it's your server), not a regular long-term solution.

Answer (score -1):

Please run:

```
SELECT name, log_reuse_wait, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases
```

and see what is the `log_reuse_wait` for your problem db
if it is replication that this is error you need this value 0, 2 or 4