# Database size bigger after delete from table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, size

After I delete huge amount of data from a SQL Server database table, the database size increased.

When I run `sp_spaceused` it shows me 2625.25 MB. It used to be ~ 1800.00 MB before I deleted from table.

Is there any specific reason it keeps growing even if I delete data?

Comment: I don't know tsql but it may simply be a temporary transaction log.

Comment: This is exactly the reason, after I delete temporary files it is OK right now. Thanks!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628/how-do-you-clear-the-transaction-log-in-a-sql-server-2005-database

Comment: I made it a community wiki answer (no rep point to me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A temporary transaction log is often the reason for a notable increase of size after a huge delete.

It will eventually disappear on its own but you may remove the files if you need to reclaim the space.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are using SQL Server (`sp_spaceused`). Deleting is logged, so your log file has grown.

See [SQL Server 2008 log will not truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646845/sql-server-2008-log-will-not-truncate-driving-me-crazy) on how to truncate your log (depending on your DB and recovery model), and then you can run

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(N)
```

to reclaim lost space

**Edit** As per @Aaron, Truncating is also a logged operation. Answer corrected.

Comment: TRUNCATE is also logged. Where do people learn these myths that TRUNCATE is not logged?

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for pointing this out. I believe I know where I picked up this misconception - the SQL 2000 and previous command 'BACKUP LOG DB WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY' probably fused my (and other's) synapses into associating 'truncate' with bypassing logging.

Comment: [Truncate has significantly less logging though](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7677/3690)