# Deleting rows from SQL Server increased the database size

Tags: sql-server, database, database-indexes, database-optimization

I have written some code in C# that deletes records from a database. It's your straightforward SQL delete code enclosed in a transaction.

```
using (SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
    //some delete code
    trans.Commit();
}
```

I have deleted about 4 million rows across 4 tables in my database. When I checked the database backup size of both DBs via Windows Explorer, the size has dramatically increased about thrice

- Before deletion: **7GB**
- After deletion: **28GB**

I confirmed that both the **MDF** and the **LDF** files increased in size. I also noticed that some tables that are not affected by the delete have their index size increased.

**After deletion:**

[image]

**Before deletion:**

[image]

My goal is to delete records to reduce the database size but it increased instead. Can you tell me why the size is increasing?

**EDIT:**

**After deletion:**

- **database_size:** 61050.69 MB
- **unallocated space:** 9592.60 MB
- **reserved:** 303512 KB
- **data:** 207040 KB
- **index_size:** 53024 KB
- **unused:** 43448 KB

**Before deletion:**

- **database_size:** 10067.88 MB
- **unallocated space:** 16.69 MB
- **reserved:** 7290176 KB
- **data:** 2937656 KB
- **index_size:** 4324848 KB
- **unused:** 27672 KB

Comment: This is more appropriate for dba.se, since the reason for this (and the answer) has nothing to do with C#. Any `DELETE` that deletes lots of rows in one transaction will demonstrate this issue.

Comment: I would expect the LDF to definitely increase, and the MDF to at least stay the same size but probably increase. So give us some numbers. And use `sp_spaceused` to work out how much space is used and how much space is reserved. Normally a delete will free up space in a MDF but won't decrease the actual file (since it will probably just need to grow it again)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database size bigger after delete from table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865201/database-size-bigger-after-delete-from-table)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid added `sp_spaceused` data, please see EDIT

Comment: I thought sp_spaceused split out log and data files but clearly it doesn't. This link has a handy query to find used and free space in your data and log files. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59406/free-space-of-mdf-and-ldf-does-not-match-with-database-free-space What I suspect is that you'll have a lot of free unlreleased space in your data file. Are there other operations ocurring in this database?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid not that I know of. it's really just a straightforward delete

Answer (score 2):

when you delete records then it log to transaction log.
so by deleting so many records,transaction log size increases.

So i think you have to clear/reset transaction log (Google it)
 and at the same time you have  reorganise indexes .

Both steps are mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting rows in a database will not decrease the actual database file.

You need to compact the database after row deletion.

Please see below link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If there are clustered indices for the tables where the rows were deleted, the deletion may either leave the size of the tables and indices unchanged or even increase them. Often, the primary key for table is based on a clustered index.

In this situation, you should rebuild the indices using the command

```
alter index _indexName on _tableName rebuild
```

where _indexName is the name of the clustered index.

see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql