# T-SQL BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT within a WHERE Loop fails when deleting records

Tags: sql-server, transactions

The following code is designed to loop through and delete transactions by the month. However, it did not perform in the manner that I expected. I was expecting the COMMIT to occur after each DELETE.

The routine failed when it ran out of log space and rolled back **ALL** of the transactions that it deleted. The `COMMIT` did not perform in the manner that I was expecting. In an effort to control the log space I assumed the `COMMIT` within the loop would `COMMIT` each monthly delete and therefore, prevent the log space from over filling.

```
DECLARE @MaxPostDate AS DATE = '2021-01-31'
DECLARE @MinPostDate AS DATE = '2019-07-01'

DECLARE @NbrOfMonthsToMaintain As INT = 13 

WHILE @NbrOfMonthsToBeDeleted >= 0
BEGIN 

    SELECT @NbrOfTransactions = COUNT(*) 
    FROM [dbo].[Transaction] f
    WHERE f.[PostDate] BETWEEN @StartingDeleteDate AND EOMONTH(@StartingDeleteDate)

    PRINT 'Delete ' + FORMAT(@NbrOfTransactions,'N0') + ' transactions between ' 
                    + CAST(@StartingDeleteDate As VARCHAR(20)) + ' AND ' 
                    + CAST(EOMONTH(@StartingDeleteDate) AS VARCHAR(20))
 
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            DELETE f
            FROM [dbo].[Transaction] f
            WHERE f.[PostDate] BETWEEN @StartingDeleteDate AND EOMONTH(@StartingDeleteDate)
            AND f.[PostDate] <= @DeleteToDate

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        INSERT INTO [app].[DataDeletionHistory](
             [DataType] 
            ,[Description]
            ,[DateDeleted]
            ,[MonthDeleted]
            ,[RowsDeleted])
        SELECT 'Transactions'    As DataType
           ,'Delete'             As [Description]
            ,GetDate()           AS DateDeleted
            ,@StartingDeleteDate AS MonthDeleted
            ,@NbrOfTransactions  AS RowsDeleted


    SET @StartingDeleteDate = DATEADD(m,1,@StartingDeleteDate)
    SET @NbrOfMonthsToBeDeleted = @NbrOfMonthsToBeDeleted - 1

END;
```

Following are the results:

```
Delete 15,183,513 transactions between 2019-07-01 AND 2019-07-31

(15183513 rows affected)

(1 row affected)
Delete 14,999,308 transactions between 2019-08-01 AND 2019-08-31

(14999308 rows affected)

(1 row affected)
Delete 14,292,165 transactions between 2019-09-01 AND 2019-09-30

(14292165 rows affected)

(1 row affected)
Delete 15,365,025 transactions between 2019-10-01 AND 2019-10-31

(15365025 rows affected)

(1 row affected)
Delete 14,576,586 transactions between 2019-11-01 AND 2019-11-30

(14576586 rows affected)

(1 row affected)
Delete 15,316,013 transactions between 2019-12-01 AND 2019-12-31

(15316013 rows affected)

(1 row affected)
Delete 15,453,046 transactions between 2020-01-01 AND 2020-01-31

(15453046 rows affected)

(1 row affected)
Delete 14,408,066 transactions between 2020-02-01 AND 2020-02-29
```

> Msg 9002, Level 17, State 4, Line 50
> The transaction log for database 'MyDatabase' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'.
>
> Msg 9002, Level 17, State 4, Line 1
> The transaction log for database 'MyDatabase' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'.
>
> Msg 3314, Level 21, State 3, Line 1

Comment: Side note, if you want to know how many rows you have deleted, I would strongly recommend against doing a `COUNT` before hand; you're hitting the table twice which will likely really slow your query down. Why not `PRINT` *after* the `DELETE` and include the value of `@@ROWCOUNT`?

Comment: FYI, you don't need an explicit transaction since each delete is automatically committed by default. Add a TRY/CATCH to stop processing after an error. It may be you previously left a transaction open and did not rollback after a previous error. Add SET XACT_ABORT with batches with explicit transactions to ensure a rollback.

Comment: There is no point in having an explicit transaction around a single statement. Also if it rolled back all of the deletes presumably there is an outer transaction anyway.

Comment: We are configured as a **SIMPLE** database

Comment: Dan, I am not familiar with the approach of SET XACT_ABORT OFF that you are suggesting (I am a rookie SQL coder) How can I see what the current state is of XACT_ABORT prior to setting it to OFF?

Comment: @Elroy, I recommend `SET XACT_ABORT ON` in T-SQL scripts/procs with explicit transactions so that the transaction is rolled back immediately in the event of an error or timeout. You don't need to check if it's already set. Additionally, I suggest a standard catch block of `BEGIN CATCH IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK; THROW; END CATCH;`

Comment: Thanks Dan, that is clear.  I will apply your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check  it,

```
DECLARE @MaxPostDate AS DATE = '2021-01-31'
DECLARE @MinPostDate AS DATE = '2019-07-01'

DECLARE @NbrOfMonthsToMaintain As INT = 13 
begin try

SET NOCount ON
SET XACT_ABORT ON
WHILE @NbrOfMonthsToBeDeleted >= 0
BEGIN 

    --SELECT @NbrOfTransactions = COUNT(*) 
    --FROM [dbo].[Transaction] f
    --WHERE f.[PostDate] BETWEEN @StartingDeleteDate AND EOMONTH(@StartingDeleteDate)

    set @StartingDeleteDate=EOMONTH(@StartingDeleteDate)
   
 
        --BEGIN TRANSACTION

            DELETE f
            FROM [dbo].[Transaction] f
            WHERE (f.[PostDate]>= @StartingDeleteDate AND f.[PostDate]<= @StartingDeleteDate)
            --AND f.[PostDate] <= @DeleteToDate

        --COMMIT TRANSACTION

        @NbrOfTransactions =@@RowCount

         PRINT 'Delete ' + FORMAT(@NbrOfTransactions,'N0') + ' transactions between ' 
                    + CAST(@StartingDeleteDate As VARCHAR(20)) + ' AND ' 
                    + CAST(@StartingDeleteDate AS VARCHAR(20))

        INSERT INTO [app].[DataDeletionHistory](
             [DataType] 
            ,[Description]
            ,[DateDeleted]
            ,[MonthDeleted]
            ,[RowsDeleted])
        SELECT 'Transactions'    As DataType
           ,'Delete'             As [Description]
            ,GetDate()           AS DateDeleted
            ,@StartingDeleteDate AS MonthDeleted
            ,@NbrOfTransactions  AS RowsDeleted


    SET @StartingDeleteDate = DATEADD(m,1,@StartingDeleteDate)
    SET @NbrOfMonthsToBeDeleted = @NbrOfMonthsToBeDeleted - 1

END
end try
begin catch
if(@@ROWCOUNT>0)
Rollback;
Throw;
end catch
```

You can als use `Output Deleted` to know the `count(*)`

You can also play with Primary Key of tblTransaction to do bulk delete or batch delete.

[Link 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223809/move-large-number-of-rows/223987#223987)
[Link 2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190140/why-does-my-delete-command-require-huge-amount-of-temporary-run-storage/190375#190375)
[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024435/deleting-rows-from-sql-server-increased-the-database-size/37024729#37024729)